# JQuery input field focus inside angularjs demo modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I try to apply a demo modal shown in url:

```
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
after "Varying modal content based on trigger button".
```

And also use a html code

```
<input name="email" type="email" id="email" />
```

...and javascript code

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Log In')
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val("This Body..")
  $(this).find('#email').focus();//why it doesn't work????????
})
```

How to set the focus function in email-input automatically?
Thank you

Comment: You should use `shown.bs.modal` event instead of `show.bs.modal` please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `shown.bs.modal` instead of `show.bs.modal`

Try something like below:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Log In')
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val("This Body..")
  $(this).find('#email').focus(); //now it will work
})
```